# localhost:8000 keeps on loading without any error or proper output

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

I am only learning laravel, and i am unable to load my laravel homepage on localhost:8000, from i long time it was going fine, but today i updated my composer and updated entry of :
config/app.php
 in aliases::

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

in providers::

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and composer.jason file:
in require::

```
"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
```

now, 
localhost:8000 is causing errors. It is not showing any error but it just continues to load.

Comment: Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for errors.

Comment: And give permissions to storage/ chmod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this issue is with clearing cache. You can run following command to clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Hope this answer will help you well!

Answer (score 0):

create .env file(copy from .env.example) and set

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Comment: It's already there:: APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:VHzZ7AS9qyQ7MDVbiToLi4OwLkoCg6td/KRNM6wvZAM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=larw
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your `access.log` and `error.log` files in your Apache server `logs` folder (mine is here: `c:\Apache\Apache2.2\logs\`)